# Cypher support in scala

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher

Is there any support for Cypher in Scala to perform operations like insertion, deletion and updation on neo4j nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend AnormCypher:

https://github.com/AnormCypher/AnormCypher

It's a Cypher take on the Anorm lightweight SQL wrapper library in Play 2.0. You still have to write Cypher queries (which isn't a bad thing), but it will make extracting the results very easy.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert on embedded use but you should be able to just use the Java API, no?  Cypher itself is written in Scala so there might be a lower-level Scala-ish API too. I've not tried it, but there's also Fakod's [neo4-scala](https://github.com/FaKod/neo4j-scala#simple-cypher-support) which appears to have some Cypher support.